# On click check how many <li> of a <ul> have the class active and show an alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a way to check on click of an item how many `<li>` inside a `<ul>` has the class active.

For example: I have a list of items and every time I click on one of the items I add an active class. I then need to loop through all the items on every click and see how many of the items have the active class and then log that in an alert.

This is what I currently have:

```
let selectList = $('ul');
let selectItems = $('ul li');
let count = $(selectList).children('li.active').length;

$(selectItems).on('click', function() {
    $(selectItems).each(function() {
        console.log(count);
    });
});
```

This seems to be logging all the `<li>` inside the `<ul>` and not the amount of with `<li class="active">`

Comment: You can try any of these `$(this).closest('ul').find('li.active')` or `$(this).siblings('.active')`

Comment: @Rajesh great! Thank you if you are willing to write the answer I will accept yours as it was the quickest otherwise I will just accept gurvinder372 answer

Comment: I'm just glad I was able to help in any way. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to count **when** the `click` happens, while you are calculating it beforehand and displaying the same `count` value,

```
$(selectItems).on('click', function() {
    console.log( $(this).closest( "ul" ).children('li.active').length; );
});
```